# Выражение "рубаха-парень"

Tags: фразеология

Почему о простом, открытом человеке говорят "рубаха-парень"?

Answer (score 2):

Первоначальным значением слова рубаха могло быть `грубый, сильный, простой человек, т.е. из простого народа, небогатый.Само слово "рубаха" имеет оттенок легкой пренебрежительности, как и "рубище". Суффикс -аха придавал корневому элементу rub- яркую экспрессивную фамильярную окраску:простой, весёлый,   свой среди простого народа, бесхитростного и простосердечного, которого все обманывают. 
До середины XIX в. носило областной характер. Оно вошло в «Опыт областного великорусского словаря» (1852), где отмечено: «Рубаха, и, с. ж. Простой человек, простяк.(простота хуже воровства)" Эко парень-то рубаха".- с лёгким пренебрежением. Потом зтот оттенок ушёл, осталось значение "свой парень" - простой, весёлый, всегда и везде свой.